# Is the toilet bowl's coating the secret to a clean flush?

Tags: toilet

*Note: I am in Australia, which has very different toilet systems to the USA, which is why this [similar question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21482/what-to-look-for-in-a-new-replacement-toilet) was no help to me.*

I have two bathrooms, which are both being renovated, and I will be replacing the toilet suites.

One of the toilets has problems with... for want of a more delicate way to put it... skid marks. The other is absolutely fine. I want to avoid this problem with the new toilets.

I spoke to a salesman today who said it was all due to the *coating* on the bowl and recommended an [expensive brand](http://www.laufen.com/wps/wcm/connect/laufen_com/en/products/features-and-benefits/sanitary-ware/lcc-laufen-clean-coat) that he said was the best.

I am dubious. I suspect the cause is something to do with the geometric design - the relative location of the water to the back of the seat, or similar, so the waste never hits the sides. The toilet that has no problems is a [reasonably cheap brand](https://www.caroma.com.au), but a discontinued model so I can't just get two more of those.

Is it all about the coating? If it is about the physical shape, is there something I can look out for in the showroom?

Comment: Do you have kids, or is it just adults?  Is this a round or elongated toilet that you are looking for, or is that a thing in Australia?

Comment: Adults. Elongated. Does it matter?

Comment: can you apply a waterproof non-stick coating to the skid mark prone area? Even clear gloss acrylic might help. If the glaze is scratched by metal, from a brush or snake, then any toilet accumulates gunk in that spot.

Comment: @dandavis: I understand the idea, for trying to save a damaged toilet, but some toilets are worse than others, even when they are new. The problem toilet has been a problem since day 1, and I want to get it right this time, even if that means paying for it.

Comment: @W.C.Fields, I ask because I have kids and they don't/can't sit very far back on an elongated.  When... material hits the front part of the toilet that has little to no water in it, streaks are all but guaranteed.  I guess what I'm saying is that the depth and size of the water "pool" is important.  Some toilets don't have a very large pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative position of the seat to the sewer drain in the floor beneath the toilet varies between models.

Some models have the sewer relatively far forward compared the seat - or at least, they are designed to accommodate such set-ups. They cannot have a "straight back" or "straight drop" at the back of the bowl, near the rear of the seat. Instead, the back of the bowl comes forward before the water. This leaves an area at the back where there waste can hit the bowl rather than the water.

The solution seems to be to find a model of toilet which has a bowl with a straight back - this might mean ensuring the sewer drain is closer to the wall, or that the toilet seat comes out from the wall further.

I believe this is the secret, not coatings, although it is difficult to prove I am right.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that the smoothness of the porcelain is a factor; a newer bowl or a higher quality one will have less of a problem.

Many brands of [washlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washlet) will spray water on the inside of the bowl before you start, which does wonders for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with the glazing of the surface of the porcelain. But on the heels of that you don'e need an expensive toilet to get quality glazing.  Welcome aboard.

Comment: As a footnote to this answer: From other questions here, I have the impression that use of aggressive/abrasive cleaners can damage the glazing. So it might be that the problem toilet is damaged rather than inherently inferior.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Good suggestion, but it was a problem since new. (The problem toilet is only 3 or 4 years old. The good toilet is going on 17 years.)