# Weak Flush can replacing Overflow tube help?

Tags: toilet

Hello I have a water conserving dual flush toilet that recently has clogged up and had use plunger to clear but it appears that not flushing with enough water to clear bowl and then results in Clog requiring plunger.  Tested with only water in bowl and not even emptying bowl each time. Tried adjusting tank fill level and it helped a little but now Overflow tube to short to allow to fill with more water and tank is still only half full(I think it"s just way they built this brand dual flush take system because flush buttons are located on top of tank cover). I thought if I could just get tank to fill with little more water then it would provide enough water during power flush to empty bowl and generate suction that helps to empty bowl before it starts refill process?  On special note.. if I use bucket and pour into bowl it flushes just fine..  that is why i thought if could just get water water during flush.

Comment: Does the water swirl when you flush? If not much, you've likely got mineral build up in the rim channels, which are fed through the overflow tube. Muriatic acid is the cure. Here we are: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11115/toilet-not-always-flushing-fully-what-could-be-wrong/11132#11132

Comment: There should be a "max water level" line on the inside wall of the tank. If your tank level is below this then you should be able to adjust that. I assume this is a recent problem; is the level lower than the "historical" level, which should be visible as a water mark line on the inside tank wall?