# Quick fix for a toilet that flushes water past the waste material?

Tags: toilet

I've recently moved into a rented property with a dual-flush toilet. When flushing the new water seems to be sent directly *under* any paper/waste that's in the bowl, causing it to "roll" over the top and not evacuate down the pipe. This happens whether one or both of the buttons are pressed/held to flush, and it's starting to get a little embarrassing when we have guests round.

Since it's a rented property there isn't an option to replace anything, but I wondered if there were any quick fixes I could apply?

**EDIT**

A littie further information; the toilet seems reasonably new, there doesn't seem to be any blockages around the rim and and we've cleaned everything. The pressure is good; the water reaches right round to the front of the bowl where it creates a good jet, but it's this jet that seems to run directly under the waster causing it to roll.

**More edits**

I doubt it's a problem with the water pressure - the jet is powerful, maybe a little too powerful, which could be why it's flushing directly under the waste rather than over it, pushing it down. We've cleaned it thoroughly, though it wasn't necessary as there were no deposits or blockages. I've a feeling that it may simply be a design fault of the bowl. :(

Comment: Is water coming out of all of the jets around the rim of the toilet, and if not, do you see surface deposits that can be cleaned or is there a blockage further up?

Comment: BMitch is suggesting not enough water is dumping into the bowl. If there were enough water, everything would eventually be evacuated, regardless of where the jet points. There might also be some way of adjusting how much water is used to flush, but with all these water conservation rules, maybe not :(

Comment: In addition to adjusting how much water is dumped per flush, it could also be a partial blockage or lack of venting that is preventing waste water from draining fast enough. Try dumping a bucket of water in the toilet to see if it drains quickly.

Comment: It's starting to sound like BMitch's latest thoughts is the likely problem, partial blockage or poor venting. Did you try the bucket test? What happened? It's somewhat common for something like a toothbrush to get wedged in the trap, the toilet functions, but not properly. This would be a fixable problem. Let's hope it's not a venting problem.

Comment: You have the reverse of this problem [Huge Bubble When Toilet Flushes, Why?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/63509/huge-bubble-when-toilet-flushes-why) - all of it is coming out of the siphon jet, and none of it is coming out from under the rim.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do my toilets flush slowly and often incompletely?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8969/why-do-my-toilets-flush-slowly-and-often-incompletely)

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you understand how the toilet works? 
Commercial toilets actually fire a jet of water down the drain to get syphon started while the bowl continues to fill from the water entering the top. I believe this is the design you are describing and it is supposed to do this.