# How do I fix a slow toilet flush?

Tags: toilet

If I press the toilet handle or pour a bucket of water down the toilet, the water flows down slowly.  What can I do to find out the cause of the issue along with steps to fix it.

I've tried cleaning that little hole at the bottom of the bowl, still no success. Solids don't seem to flow down.

## It fixed itself

After a day of not using the toilet, I flushed it. The water rose to the top then slowly goes down halfway in the bowl when suddenly, all of it got sucked out of the toilet.  It is now flushing properly after a couple of tries.

I live on the 17th floor of an apartment building.  Does anyone know what could have caused it to fix itself?

Comment: Possible dup, see if the end of this answer helps: http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/8974/2196

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a [similar question's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/8974/2196)

> If the toilet still drains slowly, then you have a blockage that may
>   not be solved with a new toilet. It could be an improperly installed
>   wax seal, perhaps the drain line isn't properly sized, or there's
>   something that can be snaked out. It's also possible you could have a
>   venting issue, but I'd expect bubbles, gurgling, or bad smells with
>   your other plumbing if that were the case.

Comment: it just fixed itself, do you know what could have caused that?

Comment: @ThierryLam Sounds like a partial blockage that got dislodged.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given sufficient information with your description; even with a toilet in perfect considition, it will flush "slowly" or inadequately, if you pour water slowly into the bowl, from a bucket.

Throw the water from your bucket into the toilet with great vigor.  The toilet should flush instantly, with very little water left in the bowl.

If, with the vigorous bucket throw, you still see impeded flush, than you have an obstruction in the throat of the toilet.  This requires removal of the toilet, and inverting it.  It's a nasty job.

There are other reasons for inadequate flushing, but your use-of-bucket description eliminated them.  They involve failures in the tank-to-bowl circuit.

Comment: it just fixed itself, do you know what could have caused that?

Answer (score 0):

There are five things that will cause a slow-flush toilet, and you need to check all of them as possible causes.

> 1. partly filled tank
> 2. clogged drain trap
> 3. clogged rim jets
> 4. clogged siphon jet, and
> 5. blocked air vent.

You can see more about each of these [here](http://quezi.com/21030).

Comment: Link only answers are not helpful, especially if the link dies.  Please consider summarizing the information in the link here, so it can live on as long as this question does.