My toilet is flushing too slowly to clear debris
My toilet when it is flushed, will take down the water and replace it with new water but leaves anything else in the bowl. I have tried plunging it and it gets everything down but after flushing it again it goes back into the same cycle. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

The cistern is dispensing water a bit too slowly.

How old is the toilet? Newer toilets put a bit of pressure behind the flush, forcing the bowl to empty more completely. When I switched two toilets to high-efficiency models, using less water, I was surprised to find them far more effective than the old ones!

To test, use a bucket with 2 gallons of water and empty it in seconds

Check the flapper chain, too loose and will not open enough.  Also check the holes under the rim are open.  Check water level in the tank.

This may help https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8969/why-do-my-toilets-flush-slowly-and-often-incompletely :)

It's helpful to ask if you have young children who are curious about the magic porcelain portal.

You have slow flow, either from a malfunctioning flush cycle or a partial drain blockage. Investigate those.

Flush another toilet and watch how quickly the tank empties and how the mechanism behaves. Compare the faulty one.

Dump a bucket of water into the bowl and see if it drains quickly and smoothly.



If you have a North American style toilet often the problem is debris hung up at the floor flange.
Remove the toilet at floor, clear tooth brushes, combs, and rags. Then replace wax ring with a new single ring that doesn't have plastic centering funnel.
If you haven't removed a toilet before spend an hour watching "replace wax ring" youtube videos.

I agree, but pulling the toilet is a last resort in my book. It's not a difficult job, but it's far from pleasant and takes a while to clean up and reset.

@isherwood Agreed, it is def a job  for dishwashing gloves and bleach wipes!
